# Docker image runs well on docker desktop, but fails when it is on google cloud run, why?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-run

need some help with my docker container, which I am using to scrape websites.

I am using selenium stealth and chromedriver, which I have installed in my dockerfile.

My container runs perfectly well on Docker desktop.
However, the most perplexing thing is that when I tried deploying it on cloud run, it failed to work and kept giving this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/scrape_websites_docker/mothership.py", line 1, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'
```

Why is this so? How is it that the container can run fine locally and able to find selenium, but on cloud run it fails? Isn't docker suppose to solve this problem of ensuring that the code runs across different environments?

Here is my dockerfile:

```
ARG PYTHON_VERSION=3.10.12
FROM python:${PYTHON_VERSION}-slim as base

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget gnupg2 curl

# Adding trusting keys to apt for repositories
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -

# Adding Google Chrome to the repositories
RUN sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list'

# Updating apt to see and install Google Chrome
RUN apt-get -y update

# Magic happens
RUN apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable

# Get the installed version of Chrome
RUN google-chrome-stable --version | awk '{ print $3 }' > /tmp/chrome_version

# Installing Unzip
RUN apt-get install -yqq unzip

# Download the chrome driver
RUN wget -q https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$(google-chrome --sandbox --version | grep -oE '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+')/chromedriver_linux64.zip || wget https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/$(google-chrome --sandbox --version | grep -oE '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+')/linux64/chromedriver-linux64.zip

#unzip the chrome driver
RUN unzip -j chromedriver-linux64.zip chromedriver-linux64/chromedriver chromedriver || true

# Set display port as an environment variable
ENV DISPLAY=:99


RUN pip install poetry==1.5.1

COPY . /scrape_websites_docker

WORKDIR /scrape_websites_docker

RUN poetry install

CMD ["poetry", "run", "python", "scrape_website.py"]
```

Comment: If you can share the image, we can try finding out the problem.

Comment: Hello @msrumon thanks so much for your help! I have updated the original post with the full code from my dockerfile. What is particularly perplexing is that this runs perfectly on my docker desktop but the moment i move it to cloud run it fails. I m using poetry instead of pip so that I have better control over my dependencies

Comment: Looks like your script uses `selenium` but it can't find it inside the container. Try installing that package somehow. I ain't Python programmer so can't directly help you on that. However, look for a way to install it through the package manager (*poetry* in your case) or using the package manager that comes with the host OS (`apt` for *Debian* based images / `yum` for *Red Hat* based images / `apk` for *Alpine* based images).

Comment: Hmm @msrumon yes i have added selenium package already via poetry. I have a poetry file that contains all my packages

Answer (score 0):

I've actually managed to fix this problem. Using poetry was the problem. I changed it to pip install, and added a requirements.txt file, and the container worked like a charm. That was the only change I made.

If anyone knows why poetry causes this to break, do share!